# Pan, Zoom and Rotate SVG Plugin

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I'm looking for a suitable library or starting point to enable the zoom pan and rotate if possible on an SVG or series of SVG's (to achieve rotate).  The brief is to have a globe which can be rotated round and areas zoomed into and then selected or popup areas exist.

I'm aware of the [svg-pan-zoom library](https://github.com/ariutta/svg-pan-zoom)

but wondered if anyone has any other solutions or ideas.

Comment: Good example of something i'm after is here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/azimuthal.html

Comment: If you want to rotate a sphere in 3D then it is not enough just to rotate an SVG image. I would start with the example you provided and I would add zoom to it.